# Restrict Google Apps / Office 365 access from home

Tags: google-workspace, permissions, office-365

I am looking to move my small business off of POP email to something hosted. I have looked at Google Apps for Business and Office 365 but one crucial roadblock remains unanswered:

**How can I restrict access to the services so that they are only available from within the office?**

Just like how our current POP system works, I just want the employees to be able to access their email from within the office during work hours. Moving everything online opens the door to information leakage, and we can't have that.

I have found *nothing* for Office 365 and I have only found [gControl](http://www.gcontrolapp.com/) for Google Apps, but it costs more per user than Google Apps itself. I also have no experience with SSO solutions (this is a really small business).

Comment: Why do you want a hosted solution if you want to limit access to your office during business hours?  That's like saying you want a car,  but one that can't drive anywhere.  The whole point of 365 or Apps is that your employees can always access it (that's why it's called "365", for instance).

Comment: Valid point. The primary reason is because we've had more than enough workstation failures or virus infections that puts our data at risk and putting it in the cloud would at least provide us with some peace of mind.

Comment: So if I understand, you want a SaaS hosted email service, but don't want the emails to exist anywhere except the cloud, or your physical office ?  How will you deal with the 'leakage' involved in send emails to non-employees?  (Or is all email restricted to internal addresses?)

Comment: Since it's a pretty small shop, we're merely looking to protect our assets in the most obvious way possible. I know that even with our existing POP setup anyone can forward emails out to another address any time. What I'm looking to do is maintain the same level of security that our existing solution provides, even if it isn't fool-proof. We've had a couple of bad eggs in the past so we're just trying to be a bit careful about not making information access easier than before. POP email is also letting in far too much spam and we're getting viruses as a result.

Comment: Can employees access their email via pop on a laptop or iphone while at work and then take it with them?

Comment: Currently, no. The employees do their work at their workstations while accessing email via a POP client, and are not required/enabled to access their email on the go. Only the boss accesses his email from his phone.

Comment: So set up a local terminal server with an appropriately-licensed Office installation. Moving to the cloud makes your (frankly puzzling) goal more difficult while offering no particular advantages for your use case.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. After posting this question I thought about looking into hosted IMAP solutions and stumbled upon Rackspace Email. I might think about approaching this problem from a different perspective. My primary goal was to get the emails off the machine to 1. Mitigate virus infections thanks to opening attachments in Outlook, 2. Reduce spam by having a much better filter like Gmail has, and 3. Prevent data loss if a machine gets paralyzed via something like BitLocker (which happened to us recently).

Comment: @raffi How do you calculate the price of gControl is more than Google Apps? gControl is `$6/User/Year`. That is **Per YEAR**. I can't imagine you pay **less** to Google? (which should be around `$50/User/Year`)

Comment: If you have gmail accounts, yes you can access them anywhere anytime, but google has a team of security experts guarding the data 24/7/365.  You could not afford to implement that much protection locally.  At that point you just have to prevent users sharing there passwords with other people.  Google drive you can share stuff read-only or allow commenting keeping the original intact.

Comment: @Rik ... D'oh! That is totally my mistake. Somehow I read it as per month, not per year. That is a lot more reasonable. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: As a follow up to my investigations, I have found that Zoho Mail supports IP address based security features to only allow access based on specified IPs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option besides SSO, and gcontrol is the cheapest. Google is designed to be accessed from anywhere and until they implement a free solution to restrict access to IPs or times, only 3rd party SSO solutions with that feature will accomplish what you want to do.

Obviously if you want to truly restrict **all** email download to be in certain locations/times, you'll have to turn off POP and IMAP access. I use gControl and it works quite well.